# ImageView with an AssetLibrary

Tags: ios, uiimageview

assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=23B4630F-5F95-4AA9-A304-DF6F31B3FDA2&ext=JPG

In this string i have an image which is selected from photo library of iOS device/simulator. I could able to place that on Image view.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:_assets[row]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:_assets[row]];
```

I am using these two methods. But Image instance is taking null value. Suggest me how to clear this error.
[NSURL stringByDeletingPathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14636660

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library assetForURL:_assets[row] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
 {
     UIImage  *copyOfOriginalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage] scale:0.5 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

     cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:copyOfOriginalImage];
     cell.imageViews.image=copyOfOriginalImage;
 }
        failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
 {
     // error handling
     NSLog(@"failure-----");
 }];
```